# Datamodel for data storage, storing tables in one structure

Tags: database-design, oracle11g, data-modeling

Need to design database in 11g to store big amount of tables in one database structure. One assumption, columns of input tables can be only type of

1. TEXT(String size more than 500)
2. VARCHAR
3. NUMBER
4. DATE
5. BLOB

Here is my draft diagram:

[image]

Maybe I go wrong, is it any methodology or way to do it better, please help?

Comment: You are aware that you are re-inventing the wheel? What you are trying to do is what Oracle (and all other DBMS) is already doing. You don't need to store the information about your tables redundantly, it's already stored in Oracle's system catalogs

Comment: I knew that I go wrong! Can I use Oracle's system catalogs freely without permission of sysdba? Is it need some special permission or connection mode?

Comment: You can always query the metadata of your own tables. This is available through the `ALL_XXX` views or the `USER_XXX`. See the manual for details

Comment: But seems I cannot add or remove tables such as records?

Comment: If you create a table the metadata will be stored in those views. What **exactly** are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, then what you're trying to do is called a ["Generic Data Model"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_data_model).
Read [this AskTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:10678084117056) and hopefully dicide not to do it ...

Answer (score 1):

Further to ABC's answer, see also Tim Gorman's tale of a similar effort: [Bad CaRMa](http://www.simple-talk.com/opinion/opinion-pieces/bad-carma/)